# Samba4 / SoGo can't join domain as additional DC

Tags: active-directory, samba

I have a win2k server server2000.zagames.zag.com.au as a PDC and I've added a SoGo ZEG appliance (ver 2.0.0b5) to the LAN. When I try to join the SoGo samba4 server to the domain I get errors. Do I need to provision the SoGo machine before joining or set a machine password or what? Is it a kerberos issue?

```
root@sogo:~# samba-tool domain join zagames DC -UAdministrator --realm=zagames.zag.com.au
Finding a writeable DC for domain 'zagames'
Found DC SERVER2000.zagames.zag.com.au
Password for [ZAGAMES\Administrator]:
workgroup is ZAGAMES
realm is zagames.zag.com.au
checking sAMAccountName
Adding CN=SOGO,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=zagames,DC=zag,DC=com,DC=au
Adding CN=SOGO,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=zagames,DC=zag,DC=com,DC=au
Adding CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SOGO,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=zagames,DC=zag,DC=com,DC=au
Adding SPNs to CN=SOGO,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=zagames,DC=zag,DC=com,DC=au
Setting account password for SOGO$
Join failed - cleaning up
checking sAMAccountName
Deleted CN=SOGO,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=zagames,DC=zag,DC=com,DC=au
Deleted CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SOGO,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=zagames,DC=zag,DC=com,DC=au
Deleted CN=SOGO,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=zagames,DC=zag,DC=com,DC=au
ERROR(runtime): uncaught exception - Connection to SAMR pipe of PDC of domain 'ZAGAMES' failed: NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
```

I also see this when Samba starts:

```
samba version 4.0.0beta5 started.
  Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2012
[2012/09/18 02:37:45,  0] ../source4/smbd/server.c:461(binary_smbd_main)
  samba: using 'standard' process model
[2012/09/18 02:37:45,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:334(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/smbd: Failed to exec child - No such file or directory
[2012/09/18 02:37:45,  0] ../file_server/file_server.c:99(file_server_smbd_done)
  file_server smbd daemon exited normally
[2012/09/18 02:37:45,  0] ../source4/smbd/service_task.c:35(task_server_terminate)
  task_server_terminate: [Cannot start Winbind (domain controller): Failed to find record for ZAGAMES in /var/lib/samba/private/secrets.ldb: No such object: (null): Have you provisioned the ZAGAMES domain?]
[2012/09/18 02:37:45,  0] mapiproxy/libmapiproxy/dcesrv_mapiproxy_server.c:183(mapiproxy_server_load)
  MAPIPROXY server mode enabled
[2012/09/18 02:37:45,  0] mapiproxy/libmapiproxy/dcesrv_mapiproxy_server.c:186(mapiproxy_server_load)
  MAPIPROXY proxy mode disabled
[2012/09/18 02:37:45,  0] mapiproxy/servers/default/nspi/dcesrv_exchange_nsp.c:1366(dcesrv_exchange_nsp_init)
  dcesrv_exchange_nsp_init
[2012/09/18 02:37:47,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:334(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2012/09/18 02:37:47,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:334(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate:   File "/usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate", line 485, in <module>
[2012/09/18 02:37:47,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:334(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate:     get_credentials(lp)
[2012/09/18 02:37:47,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:334(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate:   File "/usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate", line 117, in get_credentials
[2012/09/18 02:37:47,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:334(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate:     creds.set_machine_account(lp)
[2012/09/18 02:37:47,  0] ../lib/util/util_runcmd.c:334(samba_runcmd_io_handler)
  /usr/sbin/samba_dnsupdate: RuntimeError: (-1073741606, 'NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO')
```

smb.conf:

```
# Global parameters
[global]
        workgroup = ZAGAMES
        realm = zagames.zag.com.au
        netbios name = SOGO
        server role = active directory domain controller
        passdb backend = samba4
        ### Configuration required by OpenChange server ###
        dcerpc endpoint servers = epmapper, mapiproxy
        dcerpc_mapiproxy:server = true
        dcerpc_mapiproxy:interfaces = exchange_emsmdb, exchange_nsp, exchange_ds_rfr
        ### Configuration required by OpenChange server ###

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/example.com/scripts
        read only = No

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No
```